# Android 6.0.1 google map exception IllegalAccessError

Tags: android, google-maps, illegalaccessexception

I got an exception but I don't know cause of it, but I just understand this error occurs on android 6.0.1 and some devices like Asus tablet P024.
It occurs sometimes and I can't catch the pattern that it occurs.
It means that exception happens suddenly and randomly when working with my application.
this links has been checked but not helpful :

[Android 6 Exception (google map?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702956/android-6-exception-google-map)

[Android Google Maps Fatal Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689341/android-google-maps-fatal-exception)

device is not root.I am using Google maps Android SDK 11.6.2(Also tried 15.0.1)

can anyone help ?

these are error logs :

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'java.lang.Object sz.a(int, java.lang.Object)' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg' (declaration of 'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg' appears in /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000008c/MapsDynamite.apk)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799044@14.7.99 (040300-223214910):27)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Have the same exact issue appearing on my Google Play console but like you can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

My problem fixed by security patch update of android 6.0.1.
I think it was and Android Operation System bug that fixed by an update.